# Optimizing code: longest repeating substring

Tags: java, optimization

I know i have some real problems with the following code (as others said). can you please help me to optimize it a little bit? Maybe some example of how to do it.

(find the longest repeating substring with length between x and y)

```
    public static String longestDuplicate(String text, int x, int y)
{
    String longest = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length() - 2 * longest.length() * 2; i++)
    {
        OUTER: for (int j = Math.min((text.length() - i -1)/2, y) ; j > longest.length() && j >=x; j--)
        {
            String find = text.substring(i, i + j);
            for (int k = i + j; k <= text.length() - j; k++)
            {
                if (text.substring(k, k + j).equals(find))
                {
                    longest = find;
                    continue OUTER;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return longest;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to optimize? The number of line breaks? What problems do you have?

Comment: some programmers said that " There are multiple problems with this code. Almost any time you have to use directed break or continue, you want to step back and say "Hmmm, maybe I've got myself in some trouble here." Especially if you find yourself writing a loop that will never actually loop unless an inner loop throws a directed continue at it, as with your loop labelled OUTER. Having significant calculations in the terminal condition of a loop is another danger signal."

Comment: Does this actually work ?

Comment: @LuciC I am with Gabriel on this one. I dont think that it is working. Could you provide us with an example of how to use this? I copied your code into my idea and setup a JUnitTest on it. Give it a string (your intro) and put as expected out "following". (it might not be longest, but it was a test) and the returned result was <""> (meaning empty)

Comment: @LuciC Also your math that you impose on your first loop is a bit convoluted. longest.length is always going to evaluate as 0. 0*2 is always 0. When I pull out the math into a seperate function it always seems to return just the length of the string. That being said, just do `text.length()` if you do end up having to do math, make a int before you go into your for loop statement and put the math there. It will be easier to read.

Comment: @LuciC I think there might be a error in your math as well. I changed text to `"longest longest duplicate duplicate"` and the returned value is `duplicat`  (no 'e' at the end)

Comment: The problem you are describing can have more that one result. There can be 2 (or more) repeating substrings with the same length, both of them the longest.

Comment: @LuciC Please update the question with this information. Please give us some more information about what to optimize. If you just search for some working algorithm you could have a look at Sedgewick, Programming in Java here: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/42sort/ There is even an implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to roll your own comparison method to compare two pieces of a string in-place, instead of using substring(), which as I understand creates an unnecessary temporary copy. It may look like this:

```
bool CompareInPlace(String text, int from1, int len1, int from2, int len2)
{
    // ...
}
```

Furthermore, instead of keeping a copy of the longest duplicat found, keep its indices from and len.
Then in the end you can `return text.substring(longestFrom, longestLen);`.

Comment: substring() in java doesn't create a temporary copy of underlying char array but refers to to the same array as original string (start and end position in this array are different though).

Comment: @Andrey - Agreed; due to the fact that `String`s are immutable, this is a trivial optimization.  Still, a compare-in-place _may_ be warranted.

Comment: This probably depends on the JVM impelementation. If yours is not open source, benchmarking will tell. But even if the JVM is optimized in such a way, keeping only indices will at least save object creation and GC.

Answer (score 1):

1. I'd try using longer variable names and making the code a little bit [more flatten](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html). Renaming `x` and `y` to `minLength` and `maxLength` seems a good start.
2. Then I'd extract out some named variables for the following expressions:

   - `Math.min((text.length() - i -1)/2, y)`
   - `i + j`
   - `text.length() - 2 * longest.length() * 2`

   Reference: *Chapter 6. Composing Methods*, *Introduce Explaining Variable* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by Martin Fowler

   > Put the result of the expression, or parts of the expression, 
   >   in a temporary variable with a name that explains the purpose.

Here is a naive version which I think easier to understand:

```
public static String naiveLongestDuplicate(final String text, final int minLength, 
        final int maxLength) {
    for (int length = maxLength; length >= minLength; length--) {
        final String longestDuplicate = naiveLongestDuplicate(text, length);
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(longestDuplicate)) {
            return longestDuplicate;
        }
    }

    return "";
}

public static String naiveLongestDuplicate(final String text, final int length) {
    final Set<String> substrings = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex <= text.length() - length; startIndex++) {
        final String substring = text.substring(startIndex, startIndex + length);
        if (substrings.contains(substring)) {
            return substring;
        }
        substrings.add(substring);
    }

    return "";
}
```

And some tests:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class SearcherTest {

    private final String text;
    private final int minLength;
    private final int maxLength;
    private final String expectedResult;

    public SearcherTest(final String text, final int minLength, 
            final int maxLength, final String expectedResult) {
        this.text = text;
        this.minLength = minLength;
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
        this.expectedResult = expectedResult;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        //@formatter:off
        final Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
                { "abab", 1, 2, "ab"}, // fails
                { "abcabc", 1, 2, "ab"},
                { "abcabc", 1, 3, "abc"}, // fails
                { "abcabcd", 1, 3, "abc"},
                { "abcdxabce", 1, 3, "abc"},
                { "abcdxabce", 3, 4, "abc"}, // fails
                { "abcdxabcd", 3, 4, "abcd"}, 
                { "abcdeabcde", 3, 7, "abcde"}, // fails 
                { "aabbcc", 3, 3, ""}, 
                { "WXabcWYabcWZ", 1, 2, "ab"},
                { "WXabcWYabcWZ", 1, 3, "abc"},
                { "WXaaWYbbWZccWW", 3, 100, ""},
                { "WWaaaaXXaaaaaYYaaaaaaZZaaaaaa", 3, 6, "aaaaaa"},
                { "WWaaaaXXaaaaaYYaaaaaaZZaaaaaa", 3, 9, "aaaaaa"}
            };
        //@formatter:on
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(expectedResult, 
            Searcher.longestDuplicate(text, minLength, maxLength));
    }
}
```

The ones which are marked with `// fails` fails with the posted code. (I haven't checked what's the cause. The test data looks fine for me but I'm not sure that I understood the requirements completely.)